# Facebook comment plugin not working mobile app

Tags: android, html, facebook, comments, chocolatechip-ui

I'm creating a mobile application with HTML5 and JS. I added the Facebook comment plugin to my application in order to give user the ability to comment. But it is not working when I create APK file, I think it will not work on IOS either.If there is another solution better than FB plugin I will appreciate it.

Thank you